# Is there a way of getting dirent's ent->d_name as w_char *?

Tags: c, dirent.h

I generate a list of files using dirent but l am getting worried about directories and files that contain unicode characters.

```
void recurse_dir(char *dir)
{
    DIR* d;
    d = opendir(dir);
    struct dirent* ent;
    unsigned short int dir_size = strlen(dir), tmp_dir_size;
    if(d != NULL)
    {
        while((ent = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            if(ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
            {
                if(!strcmp(ent->d_name,".") || !strcmp(ent->d_name,".."))
                    continue;
                folder_count++;
                char tmp_dir[dir_size + strlen(ent->d_name) + 2];
                tmp_dir[0] = '\0';
                strcat(tmp_dir,dir);
                strcat(tmp_dir,"/");
                strcat(tmp_dir,ent->d_name);
                recurse_dir(tmp_dir);
            }
            else
            {
                file_count++;
                file_strs_size += dir_size + strlen(ent->d_name) + 2;
                fprintf(list_fp, "%s/%s\n",dir, ent->d_name);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
}
```

Is there a way that l can get the ent->d_name in wide string format?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all Unicode characters in a char array, using UTF-8 format. That is probably the way your OS is storing that name, so if you want the name in UTF-16 or UTF-32 you can do the conversion using a function that takes care of that, for example [iconv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just run `mbstowcs()` over the file name. They're in UTF-8; the `mbstowcs()` function will convert it to `wchar*`.

As a side note, `struct dirent.d_type` is not very portable. It's useful as a shortcut/performance optimization, but:

- some file systems (XFS is the most well known example) will always store `DT_UNKNOWN` in that member, so your code will fail there;
- It's not part of POSIX, so some operating systems (e.g., Solaris) don't even have it, so your code won't *compile* there.

In [my case](https://github.com/yoe/nbd/blob/1dd95821b9db1f2d4456d31a81e2d8abb97b0220/nbd-server.c#L648), I've used a `switch` and a bit of preprocessor magic to handle both in the same code.

Comment: Note that while e.g. on linux, UTF-8 is normally the default charset, and thus filenames tend to end up as UTF-8 too. But the filenames could be stored in any encoding, or even an invalid encoding. The only characters not allowed are the nul terminator and the / . So you're normally better off not doing any sort of manipulation or conversion on the filenames